# How to install Toggl Desktop client?

Tags: software-installation

Can anyone tell how to install [Toggl desktop client](https://www.toggl.com/) on Ubuntu?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just [download the installer .deb file](http://support.toggl.com/customer/portal/articles/552102-toggl-on-my-desktop) based on your OS architecture (32bit or 64bit) and run it on your computer. See the [support page for more help](http://support.toggl.com/customer/portal/articles/552102-toggl-on-my-desktop#downloads)

[Toggl on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/toggl-desktop)

Comment: Is there a PPA for it?

Comment: Broken links. The page isn't available anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Open **terminal** ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following commands

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:official-toggl/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install desktop-Toggl
```

This will install Toggl Desktop Client

Comment: I've tried add repository, but I've got an exception: Error: need a repository as argument

Comment: Sorry there was space in between "ppa: official" Now i corrected it to `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:official-toggl/ppa` It should work fine now. For more details about toggl ppa. Visit this [page](https://launchpad.net/~official-toggl/+archive/ppa)

Comment: This ppa is depreciated and no maintaned.